# How to ignore logback RollingFileAppender FileNotFoundException

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I am using logback in my spring boot project, but logback log file must locate in /home/xxx/logs folder. 
spring boot cannot start caused by RollingFileAppender's FileNotFoundException exception in my MacOS machine, because of MacOS cannot create folder /home/xxx/logs.

How to ignore this Exception in my spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

As much I know logging framework don't provide any exception handling capability. It's not their job. Either you Correct log location and syntax or just remove config which you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Include a file logback-spring.xml in your classpath or resources folder and then you will be able to explicitly configure the location of the log file or you may have it print to the console instead. The config below would do just that and override the default config that comes with spring boot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```